# E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' is not signed. for ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, repository

while downloading ros2 packages i was Updating my apt repository caches`sudo apt update`, i get the following output,with **E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' is not signed.** i know that Xenial (16.04) repositories are not necessary for 22.04, i removed it from (software and updates > other software) but error was not solved so i need your help.[image: other software]

```
Hit:1 http://www-ftp.lip6.fr/pub/linux/distributions/Ubuntu/archive jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                          
Hit:3 http://www-ftp.lip6.fr/pub/linux/distributions/Ubuntu/archive jammy-updates InRelease                                                  
Hit:4 http://www-ftp.lip6.fr/pub/linux/distributions/Ubuntu/archive jammy-backports InRelease                                                
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                               
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [99.8 kB]                                                           
Hit:7 http://www-ftp.lip6.fr/pub/linux/distributions/Ubuntu/archive jammy-security InRelease                             
Hit:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                
Hit:9 http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable jammy InRelease                          
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [99.8 kB]   
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease      
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Err:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

***find /etc/apt -type f -exec grep xenial {}+***

```
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list.save:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list:# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
```

Comment: please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Comment: @jsotola is it better? :$

Comment: the error problem was solved by referring to https://askubuntu.com/a/15272/1656508

Comment: That may have eliminated the error message but do you really want to continue having a 16.04 repository configured on your 20.04 system? Does `find /etc/apt -type f -exec grep xenial {}+` return anything?

Comment: @doneal24 ` find: missing argument to `-exec' `

Comment: Missed a space. `find /etc/apt -type f -exec grep xenial {} +`

Comment: @doneal24 I've edited my question to show you what it returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a xenial repository still defined in your sources. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list` and remove any lines referring to xenial. This not only will make the warnings go away but may keep unwanted packages from being installed.